# How to do a ajax request for login

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have this in my PHP code, and it currently does the login request in the same login.php page but now i want to do it with Ajax. Basically I have this in the login.php

```
       echo '<form method="post" ><div id="login" class="login">
        <label for="login">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="logInUsername" />
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="logInPassword" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submitlogin" class="button" />
        </div>';
```

I would like to still use this but have a login_request.php or something where i can send the username and password validated and then change the `<div id=login> to say you are logged in!</div>` I can do it the conventional way, with the form post .. but now I would like to try it with Ajax.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried so far? This is how I would start:

This should get you started:

HTML:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <div id="login" class="login">
        <label for="login">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="logInUsername" />
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="logInPassword" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitlogin" class="button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#submitlogin").click(function() {
  inputs =   //grab then inputs of your form #loginform
    $.ajax ({
       url: "urltoyourloginphp.php",
       data: inputs,
       success: function() {
        $("#login").html("You are now logged in!");
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Make sure to tell that you are using jQuery.

Comment: The question is tagged with jQuery, Blender.

Comment: thank you, what i have tried is the conventional way.. but i am cleaning it up to use ajax,... sorry i am new to ajax.. just one question.. how does it expect the parameters as the inputs , comma separated? an with apostrophes?

Comment: this is very easy with jQuery ajax() and suggest you do some googling to get aquainted with it - http://heybigname.com/2009/04/15/ajax-with-jquery-a-simple-login-example/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while ago, it's not quite a full ajax login (i.e. at the end it does still redirect you), but it may serve as a basis for a full ajax login. As a plus you actually don't need https (that was the whole point of this little project).

https://github.com/eberle1080/secure_http_login/blob/master/login.php

The high level steps go something like this:

- Ask the server for a seed value (a salt) using an ajax request
- Hash the password + seed using a sha1 sum
- Ask the server to verify the username and salted + hashed password
- If it's valid, the server sets a session cookie indicating that the user is logged in
- The server responds to the ajax request with a success / fail message

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has built in .post() and .serialize() methods for wrapping up a form.

```
$.post("login.php", $("#loginForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    //pass information back in with data. if it's JSON, use $.parseJSON() to parse it.
    alert('either logged in or errored');
);
```

You will also need to edit your form so it has an id, like: `<form id="loginForm">...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP but will give you an example of how I would have done it with vbscript (classic asp) so you may try to adapt it to PHP as needed.

I, in my applications, don't use the form tag since I first used ajax. So, here we go:

```
login html page:

include jquery
<script type='text/javascript' src='your-jquery-url'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function tryLogin() {
        var inputs='userName='+$('logInUsername').val()+
                   '&userPassw='+$('logInPassword').val();
        //notice that I changed your name= to id= in the form
        //notice the '&' in the '&userPassw=
        $.post('your-login-validation-page',inputs,function(data) {
            eval('var json='+data);
            if (json['success'] == 'true') {
                $('#loginForm').html('<p>Congratulations! You\'ve been logged in successfully</p>')
            } else {
                alert(json['errorMessage']);
                $('#logInUsername').focus();
            }
        });
    }

</script>

<div id='loginForm' >
    <label for="login">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="logInUsername" />
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="logInPassword" />
    <button onClick='tryLogin(); ' >LOGIN</button>
</div>



login-validation-page

[in vbscript]

user = request.Form("userName")
passw = request.Form("userPassw")

"if is there this user"      (coded as if there was a database look up...)
   "if the password = passw" (coded as comparing the values)
      response.write "{'sucess':'true'}"
   else
      response.write "{'success':'false','errorMessage':'wrong password'}"
   end if
else
   response.write "{'success':'false','errorMessage':'user not found'}"
end if

---> end of login-validation-page
```